# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
public dynamic ogretimUyesiGetir2(int enstituKodu, int anabilimDaliKodu)
{
    var liste = (from p in en.OgretimUyeleri
                 join j in en.AnaBilimDallari on
                 new { p.EnstituKodu, p.AnaBilimDaliKodu }
                 equals new { EnstituKodu = j.EnstituKodu, AnaBilimDaliKodu = anabilimDaliKodu }  
                 select new 
                 {
                     p.EnstituKodu, 
                     p.AnaBilimDaliKodu, 
                     Adı = p.Adi, 
                     SoyAdı = p.Soyadi, 
                     AnaBilimDaliAdi = j.AnaBilimDaliAdi 
                 }).Where(p => p.EnstituKodu == enstituKodu &&                                 
                               p.AnaBilimDaliKodu == anabilimDaliKodu).ToList();

    return liste;
}
```

Error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

help me?

Comment: Use the english language to design variable and method names. What should your code do? Please add relevant class definitions

Answer (score 0):

If you change the code in `equals new` to the following one

```
equals new { EnstituKodu = enstituKodu, AnaBilimDaliKodu = anabilimDaliKodu }
```

it will work.

Comment: the problem continues. :(

Comment: did you get the same error message?

Comment: Yes, error: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.

Comment: What are the types of `p.EnstituKodu`, `p.AnaBilimDaliKodu`. Are they both integers or not?

Comment: sounds weird. Please give me a few minutes to think about anything else, because I supposed that would be our problem.